# Changing decks in test of leadership in Arena?

Tags: mtg-arena

I created a throw away deck, and entered it as a test of an idea into the current "Test of Leadership" in Arena.

Now, it appears I am unable to modify or otherwise alter that deck?  Am I stuck with a crap deck for the next 4 days of this event?

Realize this is an Arena question, but I know several readers play it, and I never get Arena questions answered on Arqade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I'd taken my crap deck, and modified it significantly.  And put in a legendary creature that was not part of Strixhaven.  Because of this, the UI didn't allow me to modify my deck.  After I removed the legendary creature, the deck appeared in the UI again.